# Nested Loop inside reactjs

Tags: reactjs, for-loop

I am new to **React JS** & currently trying to iterate a certain data to present the same in **react js** but not able to do the same. The data which looks something like this

[image: data]

Now, the final output should be look something like this in tabular format

[image: desired-result]

The things which I tried are:-
[image: tried]

[image: tried2]

The error which I am getting below one is for 1 image and for second, the code is not getting parsed.

[![error][5]][5]

So, how to achieve the desired output in react js

Comment: What did you tried already ?

Comment: @TheTisiboth I have updated my question. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please avoid using images, but instead just copy past your code (you can format it by selecting it and doing CTRL + K)
It is much more easyer to read and modify it for us

Comment: What does `listData` looks like, when you print it ?

Comment: ```listdata``` looks like    

```    
Meeting Room 1:[
    0: {field_name: "SSID Name", value: "xfcsd", section_name: "Meeting Room 1"}
    1: {field_name: "name", value: "sdfdsf", section_name: "Meeting Room 1"}
]
Meeting Room 2:[
    0: {field_name: "SSID Name", value: "sdfds", section_name: "Meeting Room 2"}
    1: {field_name: "name", value: "sdfdsf", section_name: "Meeting Room 2"}
]
Meeting Room 3:[
    0: {field_name: "SSID Name", value: "sdfsdf", section_name: "Meeting Room 3"}
    1: {field_name: "name", value: "sdfdsfs", section_name: "Meeting Room 3"}
]
```

Comment: for-loop statement cannot appear as a return expression

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko yes, I agree and understand that but these are the things which I tried but failed in getting the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use map onto an object, while you should use it on a collection. Maybe try something like this :

```js
Object.values(listData.data).map((meetingRoom) => { // your code here });
```

This will allow you to use the content inside your data object as an array of objects.

---

Edit : Sorry, I didn't understand you need to access the key as well as the value. To achieve that you can simply use `Object.entries` which will return the key (`Meeting Room 1`, `Meeting Room 2` in this instance) in the first variable and the array of items in the second variable.

Here's a quick example:

```js
Object.entries(listData.data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    console.log(key, value);
    // You could use value.map() to iterate over each object in your meeting room field array.
});
```

Note : you can also use a for (... of ...) loop like this instead of a forEach :

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(listData.data)) {
    console.log(key, value);
};
```

For more information about the Object.entries method, feel free to check the MDN Webdocs page about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Comment: Thanks for the response but in your case I will not be getting the heading **Meeting Room 1** heading for each table as shown in the above image.

Comment: I've updated my initial answer to provide a more suited solution. Let me know if you have any issues or questions !

Comment: Thanks for the response. I needed to do only a small modification to make it work for me in react environment:-    
```Object.entries(listData.data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // You could use value.map() to iterate over each object in your meeting room field array.
});    
```

    
```Object.entries(listData.data).map(([key, value]) => {
    // You could use value.map() to iterate over each object in your meeting room field array.
});    
```